# Using Ajax to submit form is not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a button that once it is clicked I load an HTML form from a different file using ajax, the code is this,

```
$( "#newDeck" ).click(function() {
    $( "#right-panel" ).load( "../HTML_files/new_deck.html" );
});
```

This is the HTML form that is loaded in,

```
<form class="form-inline" id="new_deck_form" action="" method="post">
   <div class="deck_name_holder">
      </br>
      </br>
      </br>
      </br>
      Name the new Deck:
      </br>
      </br>
      <!-- Text input-->
      <div id="deck_nam_div" class="control-group">
         <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
            <input id="deck_name" name="deck_name" type="text" class="form-control" 
                   placeholder="Spanish 101" class="input-medium" required="">
         </div>
      </div>
      </br>
      </br>
      <button id="name_deck_button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Name Deck</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

I am trying to submit it using jQuery with ajax, this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// process the form
$('#new_deck_form').submit(function(event) {
    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = {
        'deckName' : $('input[name=deck_name]').val()
    };

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        url         : '../API/deck_api.php', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : formData, // our data object
        dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                    encode          : true
    })
        // using the done promise callback
        .done(function(data) {

            // log data to the console so we can see
            console.log(data); 

            // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        });

});


});
```

I know the PHP code works because I originally used it with javascript but when I changed my code to jQuery it stopped working.

What happens when I push the button to submit the HTML form the page removes all of the modifications that java code has done to alter the page. It is as if it is submitting the page through PHP. Why isn't my jQuery working?

Comment: Have you actually loaded jQuery in your page?

Comment: You mean this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`? Yes I have added that.

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: if that is the line you are using the URL should start with `http://` like `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com.....`

Comment: you can also check the browser developer tool's network tab to see whether the ajax request is going, if so what are the values that are submitted.. also can you add an logging/alert statement to the submit handler to see whether it is getting called

Comment: also you are loading the form page using `http/https` isn't it, not with `file:` protocol

Comment: @bansi not required if the main page is loaded via `http/https` as it will take relative protocol based on the protocol used by the page... only problem is if the page is loaded via `file` or any other protocol

Comment: @ArunPJohny you are correct, but it has problems with IE 7 and 8 (if someone still uses it)

Comment: I used the developer console to see if the Ajax was being processed and it is not. When I submit the form the html page is simply refreshing.

Comment: The code you show in the question should work (properly placed onto a page). I think you have a problem with the code you didn't show. Put more details to the question.

Comment: whether the form is created dynamically? try event delegation like `$(document).on('submit', '#new_deck_form', function(event) {})`

Comment: I added more information about HTML form. I didn't think it could be part of the problem but I am probably wrong. The HTML form is loaded from a different file using ajax.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I did what you suggested and it fixed the issue.

Comment: So, that is the problem. Use **Arun** suggestion then.

Comment: var value = formData ;
data: {value1:value}

Comment: How do I close the question since it is solved?

Comment: since the issue is already posted and resolved in other posts, I have marked it as a duplicate so it is solved now